# Можешь говорить всё(,) что душе угодно

Tags: орфография

Нужна запятая?

`Можешь говорить всё(,) что душе угодно.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Можешь говорить всë что душе угодно.***

Запятая не нужна. Это фразеологичнское выражение.

---

**ДОПОЛНЕНО**

Запятая возможна в том случае, если она подчеркивает паузу, которая появляется перед союзом:

***Можешь говорить всë (пауза), что душе угодно***.

Answer (score 3):

Обычно запятая не нужна, но **варианты** возможны. **Фразеологическим** является сочетание "что душе угодно", а не "все что душе угодно".

Миниатюра:  **"Сейчас поссорятся..."**

*—  А что тебе вообще-то можно говорить?*

*— ***ВсЁ*** говори. Можешь говорить **всЁ, // что душе угодно**.*

[**Фразеологический словарь русского литературного языка**](https://phraseology.academic.ru/13086/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE_%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B5_%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE)

***Что душе угодно***

Разг. Экспрес. Всё что хочется, что нравится. И вот эти дети приходят в школу и видят: никто здесь кулаками не машет, а говорить и делать можно **всё, что душе угодно** (Э. Брейтуэйт. Учителю — с любовью).

Зная Сашкин аппетит, Юшков денег не жалел, заказывал **всё, что Сашкиной душе было угодно**. — Ну как, вкусно? — спрашивал Юшков, глядя на уплетающего за обе щеки сына. — Угу, — отвечал Сашка. — Здоровско! (О. Калкин. Поеду в город Анапу).